# Creating multiple NSURLSession objects in case of HTTPS host

Tags: ios, security, ssl, https, nsurlsession

I'd like to know is it good to create multiple `NSURLSession` objects when connecting to HTTPS host? The reason I'm asking this is because I should evaluate a server certificate during an initial TLS handshake (the server accepts clients without certificates) and the place I'm going to do that is `NSURLSessionDelegate`'s `URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:`.

But that means I should create some base class that implements this method and derive all future delegates from it when using them for other means like `URLSession:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:`.

Also it creates concerns that `URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:` would be called for every `NSURLSession` I make creating an additional overhead. As for HTTP/1.1 `Connection: keep-alive` should be a default behaviour and (ideally) newly-created `NSURLSession` should be using connections from some *connection pool*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to my question in [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/qa/qa1727/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010700) Technical Q&A:

> Since NSURLSession maintains it's own TLS session cache...

So I guess it's better to keep one `NSURLSession` if one doesn't want to TLS-handshake every time it performs a connection.